# Bring app to foreground OR open to main activity

Tags: android

I am writing an Android library that will be used by others. In a service, I want to do one of two things:

1. If app is running in the background, bring it to the foreground and resume whatever activity was previously running.
2. If app is NOT running in the background, open it to the main activity.

I do not know the main activity class and everything else I found online just kept showing examples of how to open an activity when you know the activity class.

Also, not sure if this is an issue but would my service running technically mean the app is running in the background since my service is in the app?

Comment: As it's a library, you just need to provide a way for the users of your library to specify the Activity class.